# Python 3.4.3 syntax error: invalide syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
N1 = input ("dame el valor uno: ")
N2 = input ("dame el valor dos: ")


if N1 > N2: 
    print str (N1)+ " es mayor que "+ str(N2)
else:
    print str(N2)+ " es mayor que "+ str(N1)
```

Produces

```
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    >>> 
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    >>> 
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    >>> N1 = input ("dame el valor uno: ")
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> dame el valor dos: >>> >>> >>> ...   File "<stdin>", line 2
    print str (N1)+ " es mayor que "+ str(N2)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    print str(N2)+ " es mayor que "+ str(N1)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> >>>
```

Comment: You appear to have copied the `>>>` from an earlier Python session along. After that your Python session buffer was well mucked up so the rest failed too.

Comment: so what is the correct way to do that example....

Comment: Also note that in python 3, print is a function. So you need to use print(str(N2) +" es mayor que "+ str(N1)) etc. Note the brackets.

Comment: or `print(N2, es mayor que, N1)`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, `print()` is a function in *python3*.

Try:

```
N1 = input("dame el valor uno: ")
N2 = input("dame el valor dos: ")


if N1 > N2: 
    print(str (N1) + " es mayor que " + str(N2))
else:
    print(str(N2) + " es mayor que " + str(N1))
```

This should work.